# Trouble with deleting data from sql table

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, sql-delete

I have a problem that I can't fix. Here is the code

```
-(void)deleteAllRowsFromTable{
    NSString * qsql = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM '%@'", kCatalogSaleTable];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

It is just doesn't want to delete.

Comment: IT IS no problem it is gust not working

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need the `'` around `%D` as this makes your SQL statement

`DELETE FROM 'table'`

which isn't correct.  Also, that statement will remove all data from the table, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: The method is called `deleteAllRowsFromTable`, so it probably is. Its unusual though

Comment: I need to delete all data from table! but my code is not working!

Comment: @DmitriyKalachniuk: Did you try removing the quotes?